# MySQL Trigger using function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a trigger that calculate a value base on function which is checking whether the answer is correct using function checkAnswer which returns 0 or 1

```
CREATE TABLE `result_answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `resultID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `questionID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answerID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isTrue` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isCorrect` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `checkCorrect` BEFORE INSERT ON `result_answers` FOR EACH ROW 
    SET new.isCorrect = checkAnswer(new.resultID,new.questionID)
    $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

checkAnswer Function

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE RES INT;
        IF ((select type from question where id = qID) = 0) THEN
            (SELECT COUNT(*) INTO RES FROM (SELECT * From result_answers RA WHERE resultID = resID AND questionID = qID
            GROUP BY resultID
            HAVING COUNT(answerID) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers where isRight = 1 and questionID = RA.questionID) 
            AND answerID IN (SELECT id FROM answers where isRight = 1 and questionID = RA.questionID)) AS T);
            IF RES > 0 THEN
                RETURN TRUE;    
            ELSE
                RETURN FALSE;                           
            END IF;
        ELSEIF ((select type from question where id = qID) = 1) THEN
            (SELECT COUNT(*) INTO RES From result_answers RA WHERE resultID = resID AND questionID = qID
            and getResultGivenAnswers(resultID,questionID) = getQuestionRightAnswers(questionID));
            IF RES > 0 THEN
                RETURN TRUE;    
            ELSE
                RETURN FALSE;                           
            END IF;
        ELSEIF ((select type from question where id = qID) = 2) THEN
            (SELECT COUNT(*) INTO RES From result_answers RA WHERE resultID = resID AND questionID = qID
            and answerID IN (SELECT id FROM answers where questionID = RA.questionID));     
            IF RES > 0 THEN
                RETURN TRUE;    
            ELSE
                RETURN FALSE;                           
            END IF;
        ELSE
            RETURN FALSE;       
        END IF;
    END
```

The function works and returns the 1 if the answer is correct, so the problem must be with the trigger.

The problem is that the trigger doesn't set the value when inserting.

Comment: Add checkAnswer function in your question

Comment: i updated the question, though the function works correctly

Comment: May I know which parameter takes your functions

Comment: Check if the function is really called, what parameters it is accepted, how the execution flows and so on... i.e. create debugging table (`create table debug (place int, variable varchar, ts timestamp default current_timestamp)`) and insert the records with the data into it (like `insert into debug values (1, qID)`)... this allows to trace the function execution flow. And search for a problem. PS. Save warnings too, or at least save does the warnings were generated.

Comment: Your function returns TRUE/FALSE instead 0/1. Try next: `SET new.isCorrect = IF(checkAnswer(new.resultID,new.questionID), 1, 0)`

Comment: @Jinesh ( CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `checkAnswer` (`resID` INT, `qID` INT) RETURNS TINYINT(1) )

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev thank you buy i tried that but nothing changed

Comment: I  might expect this code to throw an error ERROR 1366 (22007): Incorrect integer value: 'error' for column 'iscorrect' at row.... Try changing to varchar(10) and see what you get (on a test bed obviously).

Comment: @P.Salmon still setting value to 0

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev *Your function returns TRUE/FALSE instead 0/1.* [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html) claims that ***the values TRUE and FALSE are merely aliases for 1 and 0, respectively***. So replace makes no sense.

Comment: @P.Salmon `isCorrect` is defined as `tinyint(1)`. Function value datatype is defined as `TINYINT(1)`. So error 1366 is impossible (or it would be detected in RETURN operator) - or it is a consequence of some another problem.